# Can't use local user with LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap, flask-login, apache-superset

I'm trying to integrate the apache superset with LDAP. with the configuration that I will provide below I can log in superset web with LDAP user but at the same time I can't log in with local users, such as admin, which was created during installation. What is the problem?

Also, I'm trying to split permission roles with "AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING" but with no luck yet. How can I do that?

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_REMOTE_USER
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_DB
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP
```

```
#AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
#AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
#AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public"

#AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://10.10.0.50"
#AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False
#AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=gru,DC=lab"
#AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"
#AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=gru,DC=lab"
#AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FIELS="CN=linuxadmins,DC=gru,DC=lab"
#AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=gru,DC=lab"
#AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = "sAMAccountName"
#AUTH_LDAP_FIRSTNAME_FIELD = "givenName"
#AUTH_LDAP_LASTNAME_FIELD = "sn"
```

UPDATE -- I've tried "AUTH_TYPE = 1|2", also "AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_DB, AUTH_LDAP" . unfortunately no result.

Answer (score 1):

To use both - LDAP and DB users - you should implement custom Superset security manager which will solve the problem.

At first, you should create new file, e.g. `my_security_manager.py`. Put these lines into it:

```
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager


class MySecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    
    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(MySecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
```

Secondly, you should let Superset know that you want to use your brand new security manager. To do so, add these lines to your Superset configuration file (`superset_config.py`):

```
from my_security_manager import MySecurityManager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = MySecurityManager
```

Then you can override **auth_user_db(username, password)** method of your class with your custom authentication logic.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use both local and LDAP users you should create a custom security manager class that extends SupersetSecurityManager but also overwrite AuthLDAPView class in it.

First create a file (example: custom_security_manager.py), overwrite  AuthLDAPView with a new class that users can both log-in with LDAP and local DB accounts. Add it to the custom security manager via authldapview parameter to overwrite AuthLDAPView class

custom_security_manager.py:

```
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import AuthLDAPView
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import expose
from flask import g, redirect, flash
from flask_appbuilder.security.forms import LoginForm_db
from flask_login import login_user
from flask_appbuilder._compat import as_unicode

class AuthLocalAndLDAPView(AuthLDAPView):
    @expose("/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def login(self):
        if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)
        form = LoginForm_db()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = self.appbuilder.sm.auth_user_ldap(
                form.username.data, form.password.data
            )
            if not user:
                user = self.appbuilder.sm.auth_user_db(
                    form.username.data, form.password.data
                )
            if user:
                login_user(user, remember=False)
                return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)
            else:
                flash(as_unicode(self.invalid_login_message), "warning")
                return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_login)
        return self.render_template(
            self.login_template, title=self.title, form=form, appbuilder=self.appbuilder
        )


class CustomSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authldapview = AuthLocalAndLDAPView
    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(CustomSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
```

Tnen import it on superset_config.py and use "CustomSecurityManager" class as Security Manager

superset_config.py:

```
import os
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_DB,AUTH_LDAP
from custom_security_manager import CustomSecurityManager

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP 
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public" 
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldaps://server.yourdomain.com:636"
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "CN=Surname\, Name,OU=ouSystemAccounts,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=your_domain,DC=com,DC=tr"
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = "sAMAccountName"
AUTH_LDAP_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED=True
AUTH_LDAP_APPEND_DOMAIN=False
AUTH_LDAP_FIRSTNAME_FIELD="givenName"
AUTH_LDAP_LASTNAME_FIELD="sn"
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS=False
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION=True

CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSecurityManager
```